# NSolve cannot solve. 3 equations in 3 variables

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to numerically find the critical points of the following function in 3 variables

```
V[x_, y_, θ_] := 
  (Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + 2 x y Sin[θ]]] + Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y Sin[θ]]])^2
```

`NSolve` takes a long time and then eventually says

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

```
NSolve[
   D[V[x, y, θ], x] == 0 && D[V[x, y, θ], y] == 0 && D[V[x, y, θ], θ] == 0, 
   {x, y, θ}, Reals]
```

My question is how can I optimise this?

Comment: Why not use `NMinimize`? It'll use better optimization techniques

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1 . This seems indeed to give the global minimum of a function. I am however interested in general in possible other local minima. Is there a way to list those as well?

Comment: You can use `FindMinimum` and constrain it to work over a different domain? If you plot your function using `DensityPlot3D` you might be able to figure out what ranges to constrain it to

Comment: A good suggestion in this case. Unfortunately in general my function will have more than 3 variables